# My Bootstrap Multiselect is empty

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-multiselect

I have installed the bower component in my angularjs application,
I have a multiselect

```
 <select class="multiselect" id="mdf.modifier.id" multiple="multiple" >
      <option disabled selected value> -- select {{mdf.modifier.max == 1 ? 'one' : 'multiple' }} -- </option>
      <option ng-repeat="option in mdf.options" value="option.id" track by option.id>
       {{ option.name | highlight:for_user }}, +{{ option.price }}
      </option>
  </select>
```

And calling the javascript method from my controller

```
$('.multiselect').multiselect();
```

My multiselect is getting out as an empty multiselect.
The ng-repeat does print some options I have checked.

Comment: I would avoid using `JQuery` and use the native `multiple` option from [ng-select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: Please dont delete your question again, you did this 2 times yesterday  -.- Big dislike for that action!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to [angular-ui bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and you will be fine. Throw jQuery out of your application. Finaly it should work like in this [simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ct71o7g/4/). Please check this "[Thinking in AngularJS way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)" to learn more about not mixing jQuery with AngularJS.

#### View

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">      
   <ui-select multiple ng-model="selected" theme="bootstrap" close-on-select="false" title="Choose a person">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Pick some ..">{{$item.value}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="val in values track by val.value">
      <div ng-bind="val.value | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
</div>
```

#### AnuglarJS Application

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.select']);

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {

    $scope.values = [{
        'key': 22,
        'value': 'Kevin'
    }, {
        'key': 24,
        'value': 'Fiona'
    }];

    $scope.selected = null;
});
```